# Prevent a file from opening in a Start-Process command?

Tags: powershell, pdf

I have a Powershell script that prints a PDF file, and (thanks to help here) works smoothly, except that the PDF file opens briefly in Acrobat when the script runs this command (`$fn` is the variable that contains the path of the PDF file):

`Start-Process -FilePath $fn -Verb PrintTo("$selectedPrinter") -PassThru | %{sleep 10;$_} | kill`

Is there any way to keep the PDF file from opening briefly? I've tried adding `Out-Null` to the line, but of course it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: perhaps `-WindowStyle Hidden` helps

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, `-WindowStyle` doesn't seem to be honored when _documents_ are passed to `-FilePath`

Comment: Yes, , as @mklement0 says, `-WindowStyle` has no effect here, unfortunately.

Comment: As an aside: `PrintTo("$selectedPrinter")` is pseudo method syntax that likely doesn't do what you intend: it is the same as `PrintTo "$selectedPrinter"`, which means that `"$selectedPrinter"` positionally binds to the `-ArgumentList` parameter, where it is _ignored_ in your case, given that you're passing a document file rather than an executable to `-FilePath`.

Comment: @mklement0 - I know I'm being ignorant, but I'm not clear on what you're saying I should be doing instead of this. When I run the script, the document does print to the printer selected earlier in the script. I'm really a beginner at all this, and am grateful for any and all advice.

Comment: My comment was an _aside_ (which means it doesn't solve your problem): My point was that the `("$selectedPrinter")` part is most likely quietly ignored.

Comment: To get the `-WindowStyle` parameter honored, you'd need to pass the application executable associated with `.pdf` files to `-FilePath`, and pass the `.pdf` file via `-ArgumentList`,  but hat takes away the `-Verb PrintTo` option. Unfortunately, I have no solution to offer. Your best bet is to see if the executable supports command-line parameters that offer equivalent functionality.

Comment: Understood about the problem of getting `-WindowsStyle` honored. It's very puzzling. Acrobat is the default application for PDF files on my system, and I'll experiment to see whether a different default changes its behavior. - I changed the `"$selectedPrinter"` as you suggested, but the earlier form seems to work. When I run the script, the file gets printed to which printer I selected.

Comment: Are you sure that the use of `"$selectedPrinter"` makes any difference, and that it isn't an _earlier_ action that selected the target printer? Either way, the conceptually clear, syntactically equivalent of your `Start-Process -FilePath $fn -Verb PrintTo("$selectedPrinter") -PassThru` command is `Start-Process -FilePath $fn -Verb PrintTo -ArgumentList $selectedPrinter -PassThru`

Comment: @mklement0 - The complete script consists of opening lines that get the filename parameter, then the script that I posted in my earlier question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77843203/how-do-i-get-a-variable-from-a-powershell-button-add-click-block - without the `pause` at the end, and followed by the line in the current question, followed by `exit`. I don't `think` there's anything in it that tells the PrintTo command what to print, but I could very easily be wrong!

Comment: @mklement0 - Also, I've changed the script to use the syntax you suggested; thank you. It still works exactly the same way.